# c# mvc - how do i catch serialization errors that happen after endpoint execution?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

i'm using a .NET 6 service. I have controllers marked with [ApiController] and a standard JSON serialization for every response data.
also i have a global exception handler registered that converts all exception into a 400 status code.
for data-retrieval i use EFCore in combination with a SQL Server database.

recently i discovered that you earn a **significant** performance boost when returning the IQueryable directly without converting it into an object. but while doing it i discovered something really awful:

my model had a small mistake. it had a GUID property where a database property was filled with DBNull. now what happened is - there was no exception thrown at all. the response did successfully get created - **with a partial json**

the serializer successfully converted all the items with proper GUIDs filled, then he stumbled upon the NULL value and simply stopped the serialization and returned half of the json. of course our frontend died because of that.

now my question:

1. is it possible to catch this error and write a proper error response?
2. if not: is it then at least possible to somehow log the actual error that lead to this failure after the response is written/aborted

---

just to clarify: this question is not about this specific Null GUID handling. it's about how to handle and log any error that happens while serializing

Comment: Perhaps writing a Custom converter? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0 that handles the NULL values?

Comment: i think you misunderstood the question, that the error occurred with converting GUID to GUID? was just an example. of course as i discovered it i just added the ? and all was fine again.
but it took me like 2 hours to figure out where the problem was because there were no logs and no proper exception message.
if this happens again i'm in serious trouble. i need to proper implement exception logging

Comment: I have been thinking about this kind of problem due to a similar situation and I think the whole concept is fundamentally flawed. The response *starts* with the header that contains the status code, and then follows the data. The whole "serialize while we stream the response" is going to be prone to this kind of problem because the client has already gotten the status code. I think the only way to get a more correct status code is to do it the old fashioned way, serialize the whole thing before returning any of it.

Comment: Now, as for logging, that should be possible to improve I would assume.

Comment: yeah... i know it's the problem of serializing on the fly, but i hoped there is a concept where you can overwrite an already sent response or some other hack... 
but at least there should be a solution for logging the problem in a log file or so. on the fly serialization errors should only be limited to bugs from the developer side. mismatch of data-types, incorrect filters, unsupported queries, things like this. so if we could log them, we can easier find the errors and fix them.

Comment: now the question is just: how to log them?